# Выровнять меню по центру

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять, где и что не так, в сss не силен, вот и мучаюсь. (((

```
#templatemo_menu {
    clear: both;
    width: 1070px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/templatemo_menubar.png) no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#templatemo_menu ul {
    width: 1070px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 7px 40px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    float: center;
}

#templatemo_menu ul li {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

#templatemo_menu ul li a {
text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;    
    font-weight: normal;
    outline: none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#templatemo_menu ul li a:hover, #templatemo_menu ul .current {
    color: #162127;
}

<div id="templatemo_menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="current">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Документация</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Оплата и доставка</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>       
</div>
```

Comment: А чего вы пытаетесь добиться? Чтобы элементы списка были по центру родительского ul или чтобы ul был по центру блока с id#templatemo_menu?

Comment: чтобы ссылки в меню были по цетру страницы, само меню фон, и так отцентрованы, а вот ссылки все збились влево....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/q76ubezu/) можно попробовать, в комментариях к css я написал, что добавил, и закомментировал, что убрал.

Кратко: убрал ширину у блоков и добавил `display: inline-block` у самого меню. По центру там уже было нужное выравнивание с помощью `text-align:center`у блока с `#templatemo_menu`. Другие центрирования можно убрать: `float:center` вообще не существует и `margin:0 auto;`, который в данном случае не работает.

Comment: Спасибо!!! То, что нужно!